# What is the best way to store collection data in a realation?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I would create a react-native app. And now i'am not sure, what is the best way to structure the data in a collection.

Follow scenario i have:
I have two collection *companies* and *users*. Both collection have membership contract. So what is the best way to store the data?

Method 1:

```
{
  users: [
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "gender": "man",
    "age": 32,
    "subcollection_company": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company LLC",
        "membership_status": "REQUESTD",

      }
    ],

  ],
  companies: [
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company LLC",
    "subcollection_users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "membership_status": "REQUESTED",
      }
    ],

  ],

}
```

Method 2 (array instead of subcollections):

```
{
  users: [
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "gender": "man",
    "age": 32,
    "array_company": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company LLC",
        "membership_status": "REQUESTED",
      }
    ],

  ],
  companies: [
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company LLC",
    "array_users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "membership_status": "REQUESTED",

      }
    ],
  ],

}
```

Method 3 (the good old way like sql):

```
{
  users: [
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "gender": "man",
    "age": 32,
  ],
  companies: [
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Company LLC",
  ],
  user_comany: [
    {
      userref: 'users/1',
      companyref: 'companies/1',
      "membership_status": "REQUESTD",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to me method 1 is the best way.

Method 2 will fail for very large datasets. Say a company has lakhs of users, then 16mb limit of the individual document will breach and you will not be able to add more users to it.

MongoDB is not much optimized for joins and in Method 3, you need to join at two levels to fetch information.

Comment: For Method 1: I will have many requests to firestore database. I'am not sure that if that the right way. Because me load every document in the sub collection.

Comment: For Method 2: I think my dataset will not so much big. By the way firestore has 1mb limit each document.

Comment: Sorry I didn't got your point. Can you explain how firebase db is coming in picture

Comment: If you are sure a single company will not have much users and vice versa, then method 2 is fastest approach. But keep in mind while updating (say user), you will need to update multi (all companies that have that user). If there will be very less updates then you can go for Method 2. Basically there is no single approach that fits all situations